# Problem with file dependencies and templates on a C++ program

Tags: c++, templates, makefile, dependency-management

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Templated function being reported as “undefined reference” during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878884/templated-function-being-reported-as-undefined-reference-during-compilation)
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Hi, 
I'm having a problem with dependencies in a c++ program that only originates when I use templates. Apparently the compiler is not able to instantiate the template for a concrete type and I don't know why.

Suppose I have this library (the real program where I find this is much bigger, but *I think* this seems to reproduce my original problem):

```
//temp.cpp file
#include "temp.hpp"

template <typename a> 
void printVector(std::vector<a> xs) {
  for_each(xs.begin(), xs.end(), [](a x) {std::cout << x << " ";});
}

void printDoubVector(std::vector<double> xs) {
  for_each(xs.begin(), xs.end(), [](double x) {std::cout << x << " ";});
}
```

with this header file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


template <typename a> void printVector(std::vector<a> xs);
void printDoubVector(std::vector<double> xs);
```

And this main file:

```
#include "temp.hpp"

int main(){
  std::vector<double> foo(10,1);
  printVector(foo);
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile them with this makefile:

```
CC=g++-4.5
FLAGS = -std=gnu++0x -Wall

all: test

test: temp.o main.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

I got a `undefined reference to 'void printVector<double>(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >)'` error.

Of course, if I do `printDoubVector(foo);` instead of `printVector(foo);`, it compiles normally. If everything's in the same file, it also compiles normally. I also tried to do `printVector<double>(foo);` with no result. Apparently the compiler knows I want a `printVector<double>`, he just can't find it. :(

I don't understand this problem. I was using templates in different files before without any problems at compilation. :( Yet, it feels like something very basic that I should know at this level. :/

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13

Comment: @Bo I think it's a duplicate too. Please mark as a duplicate if you want to.

Comment: I already have voted for a close, but need others to agree.  :-) The comment is auto generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

In short, you need to provide the full definition in the header-file, otherwise the compiler cannot instantiate the template.

Comment: Damn... I really should know this! This is what I get by learning C++ from crappy books. :(

Comment: @Rafael: You should have used one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: yeah, I know... people told me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315214/how-to-learn-to-write-idiomatic-c-code) that the book I read was really bad. I fell like I have to learn c++ from scratch again everytime I stumble in a dumb error like this.